# Azure ARM template deployment for a .NET application

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to deploy a .NET application using an Azure DevOps pipeline by making use of an ARM template and storing the template in an Azure git repository.

```
##################yml file for the pipeline build#################### 

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**\*.csproj'
    arguments: '-c Release'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '-o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/web'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: 'appdeploy/'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/appdeploy'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
```

I am getting an error in the build step of the pipeline saying:

> DotNetCoreCLI: If you're using `Publish` command with -o or --Output argument, you will see that the output folder is now being created at root directory rather than Project File's directory.
>
> ##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.

Comment: how is this related to arm templates?

Comment: i am trying to automate the things using azure devops,for that i am storing the ARM template in azure repo and providing the connectivity to pipeline.

Comment: right but, did you read the error message/ it has nothing to do with the arm template

Comment: I understand there is nothing to do with arm template, but I was trying to provide holistic view of the problem. If you can help me , as to why we are striking this error, it would be helpful. We used to deploy manually the arm templates, now we are trying to automate the process using Azure Devops

Comment: @farheensultana Could you please change the backslash and check if it could work? Feel free to let me know if my answer helps to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message , this issue exists in the “build” step.

You need to define in the build task which .csproj files you want to build.

In your case, the definition path `projects: '**\*.csproj'`  has some issues.

You could use the `projects: '**/*.csproj’` to replace it.

Note: The cause of this issue is the **backslash.**

Hope this helps.